# JQuery Grid for ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a customized grid in ASP.Net MVC having following features

- Editable columns (not all) based on conditions.
- Setting backcolors of columns based on conditions.

**Please suggest me what is the best & simple JQuery library available for gridview functionality (as in ASP.NET).**

I have dome some research on this and found this library.

- JQuery Datatable
- JQXGrid (But this is paid)

Comment: you can use kendo UI framework. It has good visualization, functionality and it is easily modifiable. Also there are lots of documentation, tutorials, examples.  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQGrid plugin, its really very flexible and easy to use.

To edit any colums based on condition, you can use set editable property to true or false conditionally.

```
{
      name: 'ColumnName', index: 'ColumnName', align: 'left',
      editable: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
                        //Put some condition here, return true or false
                }, 
     edittype: 'text', sortable: false, width: 7, search: true,
     editoptions: {
                 //Custom attributes
                requiredfield: "true", reqerrmsg: "Please enter data.", 
                caseType:"alphanumnolessgreater", maxlength: 500 }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggested him Kendo UI server and only the part of the tool is paid, it is better to have ever seen.

Who advise JQXGrid is not because it sucks

Comment: We are not using telerik controls. We only want to achieve customized grid functionality in mvc. Could you please suggest some other tool.